# не обрабатывает сервлет

Tags: java, servlet

Пишу свой первый сервлет в Java EE,использую tomcat, почему-то не обрабатывается мой класс, а выдает всегда

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

вот код

```
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

//@WebServlet("/hallo")
public class HalloServlet extends HttpServlet {
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        PrintWriter printWriter = resp.getWriter();
        printWriter.write("Hallo World");
    }
}
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd"
         version="4.0">

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>HalloServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>HalloServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>HalloServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/hello</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

меня смущает что в строке поиска пишется http://localhost:8080/ee_war_exploded/
разве не должно быть http://localhost:8080/hallo ?

Comment: Сами добавляли в папки я так понимаю ? Должно  http://localhost:8080/hello , так как: <url-pattern>/hello</url-pattern> . И может , если сами с папками работали, не туда файл засунули или типо того

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tomcat добавляет контекст приложения к url'у для твоих сервлетов. Это сделано для того, чтобы множество приложений (war'ников) могли без конфликтов существовать на одном сервере приложений (Tomcat).  Этот контекст по умолчанию является именем твоего приложения. Т.е именем папки которая лежит в `$CATALINA_BASE/webapps`. В данном случае это `ee_war_exploded`. Соответственно твой сервис будет доступен по адресу `http://localhost:8080/ee_war_exploded/hello`

Comment: Спасибо за ответ он действительно там находится, еще один вопрос - почему тогда мне надо дописывать /hello, чтобы открыть сервлет, можно ли сделать,чтобы при итерации сразу выводился нужный  адрес? и еще наверное вопрос откуда взялся ee_war_exploded, ведь название класса и проекта совсем другие.

Comment: @djoni тогда добавь в web.xml `hello`  как в https://www.javatpoint.com/welcome-file-list сделано с `index.html`. Касательно `ee_war_exploded` надо смотреть как ты его деплоишь.